# Estimating a Rotated Pole given a gridded dataset with lat/lons at each point

Tags: python, coordinate-system, netcdf, regression, cartopy

I have netcdf dataset that I *think* is regular gridded dataset using a Rotated pole mapping, but the rotated pole information is wrong.

For those not familiar with Rotated Poles, the [cartopy documentation has a description](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/crs/projections.html#rotatedpole) of the projection. Check out the source code for the image for a clearer understanding - the Rotated North pole is at 37.5N, 175E (in standard lat/lon coorinates).

The dataset has lat/lon value per grid point, but rotating those into the Rotated pole using the pole data provided results in a *nearly* regular grid, but it is slightly curved, and rotated. This makes me think that the pole coordinates are wrong.

Is there any simple way to estimate a rotated north pole, given a grid of lat/lons? I guess it should be possible using a linear regression in spherical space over each column of the grid, and then finding the intersection point of all the grid lines, but that seems complex and I'm wondering if there are any pre-existing algorithms for this.

Comment: I would like to add a rotated-pole pole tag to this post, but don't have the rep. If someone else could (or could vote me up twice :D), that'd be great.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: @Mapperz: python and cartopy, mostly. Happy to use anything open source though

Comment: In your question can you explain what 'Rotated pole mapping' is as I am not sure your going to get many answers from GIS.SE as it seems a very specific requirement.

Comment: @Mapperz: Done.

Comment: Now with you see > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760566/plotting-rotated-pole-projection-in-cartopy